# Can't control focus after macro run with button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button, graphics

In Google Sheets I'm running a macro that tries to do something with the contents of A1 then clear A1 to do more work.  Applicable lines are:

```
function Gx1() { 
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    //...
    spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

If I run the macro with with Extension - Macros, all works fine.  If I run the macro by clicking a button associated with the macro, the focus is left such that I can't type in A1.  On experimentation, I find that focus is on the button, wanting to resize it (or something).

How do I get the macro to leave focus on A1 for further typing?

Can't figure out what to try to leave the focus on A1 instead of the button.